# FM BAPI_PO_CHANGE how to add item?

Tags: abap, bapi

I try to add items to existing PO.

---

**And I use BAPI_PO_CHANGE.** 
Maybe somebody have WORKING example how to ADD item to PO?
**I ALREADY CAN UPDATE EXISTING items in PO.**
I need to add some NEW.
And yes, we talking about AFS system. :(((
Thanks in advance, Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the relevent filed ON in the Xstrucuture for all the required fields.

E.g.

```
PO_ITEM-PO_ITEM = new_item

APPEND..



PO_ITEMx-PO_ITEM  = new_item

PO_ITEMx-PO_ITEMX = 'X'.

APPEND ...
```

Comment: Better late than never :)

Answer (score 0):

Try BAPI_PO_CREATE1 it will handle the AFS data needs as well. You should be able to open an existing PO and add a NEW item to that existing PO. PO_CHANGE will only allow changes to existing items. I have not used these in some time, but you can get a better idea of how SAP uses BAPI's by tracing some of the logic within as you develop your programming.